# Why does Ninveh do teshuva so quickly?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, yonah-jonah-book-of, prophecies

In [Sefer Yona 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Jonah.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) why was it so easy to convince the city of Ninveh to do teshuva (5 words!) if they were so evil?

Comment: because Yonah is metaphor. see here: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2005/10/yonahs-rebellion-and-yonah-as-metaphor_21.html

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there are simpler and deeper answers, but if we go with the Midrash that the king of Nineveh was none other than the Pharaoh of Exodus -- yes, that guy who repeatedly ignored Moses' warnings, watched his empire unravel in a matter of months because of it, then eventually washed ashore from the Red Sea (the lone survivor) -- well, you'd understand why *this* time, when the prophet comes knocking, he's learned his lesson!

Comment: 1. can you cite the source for this idea? 2. from the pesukim it seems that the people starting doing teshuva before the king even found out.

Comment: @PM It's from Yalkut

Comment: @ba could you be more specific?

Comment: @PM [Yalkut 2:550](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/treesar.html#A1878)

Comment: Who told you that the Pharaoh is the lone survivor of the red sea event? I didn't know that. Also niniveh is not in egypt. How can it be the same king? Also what's the actual date?

Comment: @user4951 it is a Midrash that is cited already in the comments. The Midrash says that he was washed up on the shores of Ninveh after surviving the splitting of the Yam Suf.